# How to Symbolicate an Expo Managed Build iOS .crash report

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I’ve got an app I built using React Native and Expo which I then exported to my Apple developer account using Expo build:ios. when I submit it for review Apple reject is stating: ‘We were unable to review your app as it crashed on launch. We have attached detailed crash logs to help troubleshoot this issue.’

Comment: Hello there, have you ever found a way to symbolicate your crash reports? I'm stuck with the same problem

Comment: unfortunately no

Comment: I actually found that they already were